# Python - Script throws error when executed in one folder. But not when executed in another

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Whenever I execute the following script: 
https://bitbucket.org/pedro_stanaka/flock-log-parser/src/1340cdb7f873f158d3778aec445e4e37ee5f2a32/main.py?fileviewer=file-view-default

Inside its original folder (as it is in the project) i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
   from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
[...] 
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 253, in <module>
class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Handler'
```

But when I copied the script (and **JUST** the script) to another folder in my computer and ran it using the same command line it worked.

```
    python3.4 main.py
```

Why is this happening? Is there any explanation at all for this behavior?
I would like very much to keep the same folder/project.

I've tried to set PYTHONPATH and it did not work as well.

Comment: Do you have a file called `logging.py` sitting in the same directory?

Comment: OH MY GOD! Bad days I'm getting through! It was that. I never saw that folder there! Thank you. Make this Comment an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I actually have a set of tools I can't use in two separate directories because the Python string library has a "codecs" module and so do these folders...

Comment: In my case I just renamed it. Easiest path since I'm using PyCharm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _CapturingHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Handler'
```

Python's `logging` module will always have this attribute `Handler`, so I can guess that you have another file called `logging.py` hanging around in the same directory.  Rename that module to some other name not conflicting with the core module.